# fast queries to refresh POSTGRES table according to another table

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I have a foreign table **A** which has columns **foo**, **bar**, **baz**, **qux**. column **foo** has a UNIQUE constraint.

I have another table **B** which has columns **id**, **foo**, **bar**, **baz** .

Table **B** depends on table **A** and firstly it is initialized by inserting all rows in **A** to **B**, while ignoring column **qux** and generating unique **id**s.

**A** is refreshed hourly and will be replaced with a brand new table after each hour. Then I need to update **B** as well.

I want to know what are the fastest possible queries to

1) update all those rows in **B** for which there exists a row in **A** with same **foo** value, and either **bar** or **baz** has been changed with the new values of **bar** and **baz**.

2) insert all those rows from **A** for which there is no row in **B** with same **foo** value.

3) delete all those rows in **B** for which there is no row in **A** with same **foo** value.

What are the corresponding optimal queries in **postgresql** which can do these three operations as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `UNIQUE` constraint on `foo` on table `b`.

1) and 2)

```
INSERT INTO b (foo, bar, baz)
   (SELECT foo, bar, baz FROM a)
ON CONFLICT foo
   DO UPDATE SET bar = EXCLUDED.bar,
                 baz = EXCLUDED.baz
      WHERE bar <> EXCLUDED.bar
         OR baz <> EXCLUDED.baz;
```

3):

```
DELETE FROM b
WHERE NOT EXISTS
         (SELECT 1
          FROM a
          WHERE b.foo = a.foo
         );
```

But I think it would be a better solution to make `b` a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-materializedviews.html) on `a` and just refresh it.

Comment: Many thanks Laurenz. But the first query gives syntax error to me.

Comment: consider this simple scenario:

create table A (foo text, bar text, baz text, qux text);

insert into A (foo,bar,baz,qux) VALUES ('AAA1','BBB1','CCC1','DDD1'),('AAA2','BBB2','CCC2','DDD2');

create table B (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, foo text UNIQUE, bar text, baz text);

insert into B (foo,bar,baz) (select foo,bar,baz from A);

insert into A values ('AAA3','BBB3','CCC3','DDD3'),('AAA4','BBB4','CCC4','DDD4');

Comment: update A set bar='NEW_BAR' where foo='AAA1';

insert into b (foo,bar,baz)
(select foo,bar,baz from a)
on conflict (foo)
DO UPDATE SET bar=EXCLUDED.bar, baz=EXCLUDED.baz
where bar <> EXCLUDED.bar OR baz <> EXCLUDED.baz;
-------------------
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "on"
LINE 3: on conflict (foo)

Comment: Oh Darn, that is because of my version of postgresql server. I should update it to 9.5 I think and have another try...

Comment: My recommendation, as mentioned in the answer, would be to use a materialized view instead, which has been available since 9.3. This is *exactly* the use case for a materialized view.

Comment: Laurenz, can materialized view populate and maintain IDs as well? Other tables has foreign keys to B's id column and I don't want to lose that.

Comment: The `id` of `b` would be the same as `a`'s `id` if `b` is a materialized view. Is that a problem?

Comment: unfortunately A does not have an id column. Actually A is a foreign table which points to a csv file and this csv file is delivered to us hourly. we can define id's in csv file but we will lose them next hour.

Comment: Then generate the `id`s in the view with `SELECT row_number() OVER () AS id, * FROM foreign_table` and you can still use a materialized view.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, but there is no guarantee that the records come with same row number as previous hour. So when I refresh the materialized view, isn't it possible to lose the consistent ids?

Comment: Use `foo` as a primary key.

Comment: I am very new to realm of DB so I ask this question. some urls are stored in foo column and these url lengths can be long. Is it a good practice to replicate this column in other tables as a foreign key?

Comment: It is maybe a bit annoying. You could gamble and use `md5(foo)` or some other hash as primary key. There *most likely* won't be a collision.

Comment: That can work, but I don't think even a small chance of collision is tolerable. Furthermore we may change DELETE to SOFT DELETE somewhere in the future. I updated the server to 9.5 and now everything works fine and fast. Many thanks :)